# Is it possible to manage bean injection by generic types in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, oop, generics, dependency-injection

I have two entities with same  structure, the only difference is they are stored in different tables. So I decided to move their fields to an abstract class:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractRecord {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "status")
    Long status;

}

@Entity(name = "record")
public class Record extends AbstractRecord {
}

@Entity(name = "adjusted_record")
public class AdjustedRecord extends AbstractRecord {
}
```

The same I've done with the repositories and also I introduced the return type as a generic in interface declaration:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractRecordURepository<T extends AbstractRecord> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    default T getNext() {
        // some logic
    }

}

@Repository
public interface RecordURepository extends AbstractRecordURepository<Record> {
}

@Repository
public interface AdjustedRecordURepository extends AbstractRecordURepository<AdjustedRecord> {
}
```

And now I have a service with a common logic for both entities, the only difference is the type of repository (and its entity type) inside of `MyService` class, so I decided to do the same with the repository type as with the return type in `AbstractRecordURepository`. An important detail is the name of repository field in `MyService` - **recordRepository**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService<T extends AbstractRecord, R extends AbstractRecordURepository<T>> {
    private final R recordRepository;

    public void getNextRecord() {
        T record = recordRepository.getNext();
        // some logic
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to inject my `myService` bean this way, once I want the `AdaptedRecordURepository` to be injected as an `R` type in `myService`:

```
@Autowired
MyService<AdjustedRecord, AdjustedRecordURepository> myService;
```

But I don't get an expected result. Generic types are being ignored while injecting and RecordRepository is being injected to `myService` every time because the name of its field is `recordRepository`.

So, my question is: Is it possible to manage bean injection in this way (by generics). And isn't this a completely bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Spring, the type of the bean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean) injected at runtime is determined by their definitions in the Spring context, not by the generic types used in your code. That means that Spring does not directly use the generic types (like `T` and `R` in your `MyService<T, R>`) to resolve the dependencies. It relies on the actual bean definitions and qualifiers to wire up the dependencies. That is because Java uses [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for generics, which means that the generic type information is not available at runtime.

You can try instead to define which bean should be injected, using [qualifiers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation) or by defining specific configurations.

First, define qualifiers to differentiate your beans. That will help Spring to know exactly which bean you want injected.

```java
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface RecordType {
    String value();
}
```

Then annotate your repository interfaces with these qualifiers:

```java
@Repository
@RecordType("record")
public interface RecordURepository extends AbstractRecordURepository<Record> {
}

@Repository
@RecordType("adjustedRecord")
public interface AdjustedRecordURepository extends AbstractRecordURepository<AdjustedRecord> {
}
```

Update your service to specify which repository it needs. You can achieve this by autowiring the `ApplicationContext` and fetching the bean dynamically based on a qualifier value, using [`@RequiredArgsConstructor` from Lombok](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lombok-constructor-annotation):

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService<T extends AbstractRecord> {

    private final ApplicationContext context;
    private AbstractRecordURepository<T> recordRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Example usage: "adjustedRecord" or "record"
        String qualifier = "adjustedRecord"; // Determine this dynamically if needed
        recordRepository = (AbstractRecordURepository<T>) context.getBean(RecordType.class, qualifier);
    }

    public void getNextRecord() {
        T record = recordRepository.getNext();
        // some logic
    }
}
```

---

> But isn't explicitly calling the `ApplicationContext` to inject beans in the first option a bad practice?

True: the core principle of Spring and dependency injection (DI) is to decouple the instantiation and management of dependencies from your business logic. By directly using `ApplicationContext` to fetch beans..., that would somewhat circumvent this principle, as it requires your code to explicitly request dependencies rather than having them injected automatically.

That was more to address the dynamic aspect of bean retrieval based on generic types, which Spring's DI mechanism does not directly support.

- either your application requires dynamically determining which bean to use at runtime, and this cannot be effectively managed through Spring's standard DI mechanisms.
- or you are developing a framework or a library where the users might need to plug in their beans, and you cannot determine what those beans will be at compile time.

But to address your concern, you can modify the approach to use constructor injection with `@Qualifier` annotations directly, instead of fetching beans dynamically from the `ApplicationContext`. Keep the `@Qualifier` annotation and`RecordType` qualifier.

Instead of using `ApplicationContext` and `@PostConstruct`, directly inject the required repository using constructor injection with `@Qualifier`. That would use [Spring's automatic wiring based on qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired-qualifiers.html) and makes sure the correct repository is injected at creation time.

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService<T extends AbstractRecord> {

    private final AbstractRecordURepository<T> recordRepository;

    // Constructor injection with Qualifier
    public MyService(@RecordType("adjustedRecord") AbstractRecordURepository<T> recordRepository) {
        this.recordRepository = recordRepository;
    }

    public void getNextRecord() {
        T record = recordRepository.getNext();
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Since the `MyService` class now expects a constructor argument with a qualifier, you would need to combine that with the second approach below: Java generics with Spring's DI container do not seamlessly support dynamic type injection based on generics at runtime due to type erasure, as mentioned.

Hence the need to create specific configurations for each entity type, which avoids using `ApplicationContext`:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService<Record> recordService(@Qualifier("record") RecordURepository recordRepository) {
        return new MyService<>(recordRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService<AdjustedRecord> adjustedRecordService(@Qualifier("adjustedRecord") AdjustedRecordURepository adjustedRecordRepository) {
        return new MyService<>(adjustedRecordRepository);
    }
}
```

That configuration explicitly wires each `MyService` bean with the appropriate repository type. This adds more boilerplate, but keep type safety and adheres to Spring's dependency injection principles.

---

Or (second approach): you can define specific configurations for each type of service you need. That would involve creating explicit beans for each type of `MyService` you plan to use.

Your original `MyService` class is designed to be generic, accepting any type of `AbstractRecord` and its corresponding repository. To use the configuration-based approach, `MyService` needs to be modified to accept a specific type of `AbstractRecordURepository` directly through its constructor, instead of relying on the generic type `R`.

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class MyService<T extends AbstractRecord> {

    private final AbstractRecordURepository<T> recordRepository;

    public MyService(AbstractRecordURepository<T> recordRepository) {
        this.recordRepository = recordRepository;
    }

    public void getNextRecord() {
        T record = recordRepository.getNext();
        // some logic
    }
}
```

With `MyService` now explicitly expecting a concrete `AbstractRecordURepository`, you can define specific beans for each service type you need. This is done in a `@Configuration` class. For each type of `MyService`, a specific repository is injected through the constructor.

```java
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService<Record> recordService(RecordURepository repository) {
        return new MyService<>(repository);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService<AdjustedRecord> adjustedRecordService(AdjustedRecordURepository repository) {
        return new MyService<>(repository);
    }
}
```

By defining beans in a configuration class, you make the dependencies of each `MyService` instance explicit. Since each `MyService` bean is explicitly configured with the correct type of repository, you maintain type safety. With specific configurations, Spring no longer needs to infer the correct repository type based on generics. This simplifies the injection process, as each bean is clearly defined with its dependencies.

But this reduces the flexibility of `MyService` to be automatically adapted to new types of `AbstractRecord`. Each new type requires adding a specific bean definition in the configuration class. If the set of `AbstractRecord` types is known and relatively stable, *then* explicit configuration is interesting.

Comment: thanks for your extensive answer, but isn't explicitly calling the ApplicationContext to inject beans in the first option a bad practice?